# MySQL Grouping sort issue

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, grouping

I have a table of users watch history. I log the 'content_id', the 'user_id' and add a timestamp in a table called 'watch_history' every time content is viewed. Even if the same content is watched multiple times in a row, every hit is logged.

I need to extract a watch history, but the 'content_id' column should be distinct and ordered in decending order from most recently watched... I'm finding it difficult to explain, but basically exactly how the YouTube watch history works (no multiple instances of the same video).

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT content_id, time_stamp, user_id, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT content_id) AS hit_count 
FROM watch_history 
WHERE user_id = X 
GROUP BY content_id 
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```

It works, but I need the 'time_stamp' field to reflect the last time that content was watched, any help?

Thank.

Comment: `SELECT x, COUNT(DISTINCT x) ... GROUP BY x` will always yield 1 for the count. You want `MAX(time_stamp)`. _Note the user_id will most likely NOT be the user_id of the record with the last time_stamp value._

Comment: try max(time_stamp) for latest one

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . The `note` in your comment is not true, because the `where` clause chooses only a single user id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh, you are correct, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  This is tolerably ok for `user_id`, because it is a fixed value.  But for `timestamp` it is not ok.

Use the `MAX()` aggregation function:

```
SELECT content_id, MAX(time_stamp) as time_stamp, user_id, 
       COUNT(*) AS hit_count 
FROM watch_history 
WHERE user_id = X 
GROUP BY content_id, user_id
ORDER BY MAX(time_stamp) DESC;
```

Note:  `COUNT(DISTINCT content_id)` doesn't make sense.  It will return "1" on each row (unless there is one row where `content_id` is `NULL`).  I think you just want `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: SInce you're grouping by content_id and user_id, and not by timestamp  isn't this going to only show one row per contentId and UserId, (for the latest Hit on each content by each user), and not include all hits ?

Answer (score 0):

do you want the hits sorted by most recent view of the Content, or by most recent view of the content by a specific viewer?

If the answer is the former, then:

```
SELECT content_id, user_id, 
     COUNT(content_id) AS hit_count 
FROM watch_history h
WHERE user_id = X 
GROUP BY content_id
ORDER BY (Select Max(timestamp) from watch_history 
          Where user_id = X 
             and content_id = h.content_id) DESC
```

or

```
SELECT content_id, time_stamp, user_id, 
     COUNT(content_id) AS hit_count 
FROM watch_history h
   join watch_history last
       on last.content_id = h.Content_id
          and last.timestamp = 
              (Select max(timestamp) FROM watch_history 
               where user_id = X 
                  and content_id = h.content_id)
WHERE user_id = X 
GROUP BY content_id, time_stamp
ORDER BY last.timestamp desc
```